# Metodo Get por parametro diferente al id

Tags: asp.net, crud

Como puedo cambiar  este método Get para que en lugar de buscar por el ID busque por otro parámetro del modelo.

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(LecturaCummins))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLecturaCummins(int id)
    {
        LecturaCummins lecturaCummins = db.LecturaCummins.Find(id);
        if (lecturaCummins == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(lecturaCummins);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente cambia el tipo de parámetro que este recoge, ejemplo:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLecturaCummins(string nombre)
    {

        var lecturaCummins = db.LecturaCummins.Where( p => p.Nombre == nombre));

        if (!lecturaCummins.Any())
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return Ok(lecturaCummins);
    }
```

y si te fijas he modificado el `if` ya que `Where` siempre retorna una colección no `null`, si deseas puedes cambiar Where por FirstOrDefault y dejar tu if tal y como está. Todo este ejemplo funciona bien cuando pasas los parámetros mediante un formulario ejemplo:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(
    "GetLecturaCummins", "Lectura", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="text" name="Nombre"/>
    <input type="submit" value="buscar"/>
}
```

Puede que tu problema esté en que deseas pasar el valor de nombre, (que es un string) como parámetro en una ruta asp. ejemplo `http://localhost:port/LecturaCummins/GetLecturaCummins/nombre_del_atriburo`. Si es este el caso, el valor que espera tu método llegaría null, esto pasa porque tu proyecto está configurado para recibir rutas de tipo Controller/Action/int:Id, para poder recibir un string en tu ruta basta con ir a RouteConfig.cs y agregar:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

ya ensima de tu método agrega lo siguiente para que permita recibir string:

```
        [Route("NombredetuController/GetLecturaCummins/{nombre:alpha}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetLecturaCummins(string nombre){
        ....
        }
```

espero te sea de ayuda